# How to get slide menu views exact height in Xamarin.Forms for Android platform

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin.forms with SlideOverKit(https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit) . SlideOverKit uses static values for HeightRequest & 
WidthRequest for slide menu. I want to dynamically set the height as per menu content, for this I am making use of custom renderer of library & overriding the 
OnMeasure() for Android. 
I am suppose to get child views height by measuring them as per below code but it always return me the parent/screen height. I tried 
differnet combinations of MeasureSpec mode & size but unable to get exact height of child elements.

SlideMenuDroidRenderer.cs inside SlideOverKit.Droid project:-

```
protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    int mWidth = 0, mHt = 0;
    int childWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(MarginLayoutParams.WrapContent, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
    int childHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(MarginLayoutParams.WrapContent, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
    for (int i = 0; i < ChildCount; i++)
    {
        Android.Views.View child = GetChildAt(i);
        if (child.Visibility != ViewStates.Gone)
        {
            child.Measure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec);                   
            mWidth += child.MeasuredWidth;
            mHt += child.MeasuredHeight;
        }
    }
    SetMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

After it calls OnLayout(), I use MeasuredHeight & MeasuredWidth to set the slidemenu height & width.

If anyone knows how to get exact size of menu view in custom renderer of Xamarin.Forms ?

TIA.